# Cannot open product detail page. Only few

Tags: magento2, megamenu, magento2marketplace

I am trying to access few pages, but this error is coming

```
Error: Call to undefined method Sm\Market\Helper\Data::getAdvanced() in /mnt/data/home/989572.cloudwaysapps.com/unshchzchy/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Theme/templates/html/config.phtml:4
```

Answer (score 1):

As we can see in the error, you have a file in your theme which is calling an undefined method.

It seems that you are using a custom theme and custom modules. The `Sm_market` theme is calling a method from the `Sm_Market` module. This kind of error might happen if your theme have been updated, but not the module.
Update your module and theme to the latest version, and try again.

If the error persists, please share more details about the following file and class :

- `app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Theme/templates/html/config.phtml` file
- `Sm\Market\Helper\Data` class